# How to bypass VirtualBox update error while installing Windows 11 update?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-update, windows-11

Issue appeared while installing Windows update 10.0.22504.1010 which is requesting to update VirtualBox to latest version.

After that, I've updated VirtualBox to 6.1.28, but it didn't solve the problem. Also, I've tried to delete VirtualBox completely from computer, but it didn't help either.

How can I bypass or resolve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to bypass this issue you'll need to

1. Execute this command in Terminal with admin privileges.

   `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
2. Restart PC
3. Try to install Windows update again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This check somehow detects even installers of VirtualBox, in my case it was in Downloads folder, and after removing it I was able to continue Windows 11 install. Previous steps were updating Docker, uninstalling all emulators, removing all keys with "VirtualBox" value substring from registro. Nothing helped.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1176759)